# How to match 1 value with contains operator when using joins in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Got two tables, left Table A has distinct values and right table B (that I need to join with table A) has duplicate values. I need to verify if a value (blah) in table B exists and for that I am using **contains** operator, however as multiple rows are matched in table B, I am getting repeated values in the output table. How to stop at first match using contains ? Any other better approach?

**Table A**
[image]

**Table B**
[image: ID Text 1 blah blah blah 1 123 123 123 1 123 blah 123 2 blah blah blah 2 234 234 123 2 123 blah 234]

```
let B = datatable (ID:long, Text:string) [ 
1, "blah blah blah",
1, "123 123 123",
1, "123 blah 123",
2, "blah blah blah",
2, "234 234 123",
2, "123 blah 234"]; 
let A = datatable (ID:long, Name:string) [ 
1, "abc",
2, "cde",
3, "def",
4, "efg",
5, "ghi",
6, "ijk"]; A
|join kind=leftouter (B | where Text contains "blah") on ID
| project ID, Name, Text
```

Output I get has duplicate rows

```
ID  Name    Text
1   abc blah blah blah
1   abc 123 blah 123
2   cde blah blah blah
2   cde 123 blah 234
6   ijk 
5   ghi 
4   efg 
3   def
```

Exptected output (no duplicate rows)

```
ID  Name    Text
1   abc blah blah blah
2   cde blah blah blah
3   def 
4   efg 
5   ghi 
6   ijk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let B = datatable (ID:long, Text:string) [ 
1, "blah blah blah",
1, "123 123 123",
1, "123 blah 123",
2, "blah blah blah",
2, "234 234 123",
2, "123 blah 234"]; 
let A = datatable (ID:long, Name:string) [ 
1, "abc",
2, "cde",
3, "def",
4, "efg",
5, "ghi",
6, "ijk"]; 
A
| join kind=leftouter 
(
      B 
    | where Text contains "blah"
    | summarize take_any(Text) by ID
) on ID
| project-away ID1
```

| ID | Name | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | blah blah blah |
| 2 | cde | blah blah blah |
| 6 | ijk |  |
| 5 | ghi |  |
| 4 | efg |  |
| 3 | def |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WQMW+DMBCFdyT+wxMTSHQA0g6pMiTKkqVTt6qqDjjAYOwKHKWp+PG1IYkitbV11qd373xnSzbYYYOSjN25ZISH/VpqVcd45S+zHs0gVB3hDb6XxAhySQ1uRxAvapJmuMS9NPsuWvpnsVPTbAUXd8ZbsdWD92fbW9pBt/8M+kI9/xqU8uJ6W1Gyw8xiyZXDlUWuaoePFutGOHyyKNpuabj1vQmtFgqdUOVGcmX00fBgU6HvYV47LDTh1PDA84+h0MqQUOPy3ODqGI99T4P4Zhjq+IPUOXT2CPkZh73vRdBqhgmfg265MA90IpdLfgC19lmqpQEAAA==)